# Change attribute after $.get

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a table where each row represents a user (populated from a database). I'd like it so when a user clicks one of these rows, some elements are appended below the row relating to the clicked row.

I've achieved this effect with the following script:

```
        $('.data-table tr').click(function () {
                $(this).after('<tr class="trow"><td colspan="6">' +
                    '<div class="trowdiv"></div>' +
                    '</td></tr>'
                );


                $.get("file.php", function (data) {
                    $( ".trowdiv" ).html( data );
                });

            }
        });
```

`file.php` is simply some HTML elements:

```
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" maxlength="255" value='' />
<br/>
<label for="email">Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" maxlength="100" value='' />
```

What I would like now is to change the `value` attributes of each `input` by adding something (after the `$.get`) like :

```
$('#name').attr('value', "hello");
```

But it doesn't work. I suspect it's because the element hasn't loaded yet?

I also get `undefined` when doing this:

```
alert($('#name').attr('value'));
```

Is there any way I can achieve the desired result? Or even an easy way to send information to `file.php`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is asynchronous. To change the attribute, you need to make sure that the html is already appended / prepended or loaded. Therefore, you need to put your

```
$('#name').attr('value', "hello");
```

or

```
alert($('#name').attr('value'));
```

into the $.get() like this

```
            $.get("file.php", function (data) {
                $( ".trowdiv" ).html( data );
                $('#name').attr('value', "hello");
                alert($('#name').attr('value'));
            });
```